# Testing controller in Sails.js with wallaby.js

Tags: sails.js, atom-editor, wallaby.js

if I use Wallaby.js in Atom test my Sails.js Controller. All e2e are broken an I allways get 404 Errors for all routes, Running the same tests from npm works as expected.

Even defining routes in freeport lift, doesn´t work.
Any Ideas?

```js
freeport(function (err, port) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Lift Sails with test database
        global.sails = Sails.lift({
          log: {
            level: 'info'
          },
          models: {
            connection: 'test',
            migrate: 'drop'
          },
          routes: {
            '/mongos': {view: 'homepage'}    
          },
          port: port
        }, function (err) {
          if (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            wallaby.start();
          }

          // Load fixtures
          var barrels = new Barrels();

          // Save original objects in `fixtures` variable
          fixtures = barrels.data;

          // Populate the DB
          barrels.populate(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            wallaby.start();
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: I may have a look, please create the issue in our repo https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues and also a sample GitHub repo with your wallaby config and a dummy test that fails.

Comment: i created an issue in your sailsJS Wallaby Demo